# SPFieldCollection TryGetFieldByStaticName bug?

Tags: splistitem, spfield

I had expected that if TryGetFieldByStaticName succeeds and returns a value, there would be an SPField in the item that has a static name equal to what I used in the TryGet... call, but no? I.e. can someone explain why the following piece of code outputs `Value: a field value` bot not `here it is`.

```
// page is SPListItem from Pages list
string stName = "CustomName";
try {
  Console.WriteLine("Value: " + page.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(stName));
  foreach (SPField field in page.Fields) {
    if (field.StaticName.Equals(stName)) {
      Console.WriteLine("here it is");
    }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this works:

```
    if (field.StaticName.Equals(stName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Same output, unfortunately.